# What is the solution to an equation means?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

OK, I'd learnt in school that a solution is the values of the variables for which the equation is true.

But Wikipedia says that a solution is an assignment of expressions to the unknown variables that makes the equality in the equation true.
So, what about the univariate polynomials which many a times only have a single number as its solution? For example, is "$3$" an expression?

PS- Wikipedia also says that mathematical expressions include arithmetic expressions, polynomials, algebraic expressions,... . So, do individual numbers fall under arithmetic expressions?

Comment: Yes it is an expression.

Comment: Note a specific distinction between an expression and an equation: an equation includes some kind of equivalence (an equals sign typically) and an expression does not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you pointed out, $3$, and any other number, is an arithmetic expression. Also, consider this equation:
$$y-x=2$$
In order to solve for $y$, what do you do? You add $x$ on both sides.
$$y=x+2 \\
$$
As you asked, in this case, the solution for $y$ is indeed an assignment of an algebraic expression to $y$.